# Why does running a python file inside a pod not have the same behavior as running it directly?

Tags: python, kubernetes, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app with the following code

```py
    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup_event():
    """Initialize application services"""
        print("Starting the service")
```

when I run FastAPI directly from the terminal, I get the following output

```
INFO:     Started server process [259936]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
Starting the service
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:3000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

You can see that the print statement got executed.

However, when the same app is automatically run inside a Kubernetes cluster, I get the following output

```
 INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
 INFO:     Application startup complete.
 INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:3000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The print statement did not get executed, in fact, any additional code inside the function never gets executed.

However, if I exit the process like this:

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    """Initialize application services"""
    print("Starting the service")
    exit(99)
```

The process exists then I can see the print statement.

```
SystemExit: 99
ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
Starting the service
```

What is the problem here?

Edit: Actually no code whatsoever gets executed, I have put print statements literally everywhere and nothing gets printed, but somehow the webserver runs...

Comment: perhaps you looking at an old image. You sure it got pulled?

Comment: @TheFool Yes, I changed the port to see if it changes in the logs and it does.

Comment: Looks like a difference of how asyncio is being handled in the kubernetes python client versus in your environment

Comment: It turns out the problem was the internal buffer not flushing the output.
Forcing it to flush: print("", flush=True) solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, actually, there is no problem with my code, FastAPI, asyncio, or Kubernetes.

Everything was actually working correctly, it's just that the output was buffered.

After adding flush=True to the print statement, everything showed.

I am answering this in case some poor soul stumbles upon this thread in the future.

I spent days debugging this!!!

Comment: I am one of the poor souls who stumbled upon this thread in the future, so thank you.